# Mapping from 1D line to 2D plane: an infinite piece of rope covering 2D plane without self-intersection

Tags: number-theory

I believe I'm looking for a function: $f(x) : \mathbb N \mapsto \mathbb N^2$ and it's inverse  $f^{-1}(x) : \mathbb N^2 \mapsto \mathbb N$, a known mapping that can take any positive integer and map to a unique 2D integer point (and the inverse mapping as well).

Like the titles says, the conceptual idea is to take an infinitely long piece of rope, and starting at the origin (0,0), map the rope to the 2D plane in such a way as to fill the space efficiently, and allow for a simple algorithm to go from (d) -> (x,y) and from (x,y) -> (d).

The mapping kind of a resembles a Hilbert space-filling curve, however, there the space being filled is infinite.

I apologize in advance, it's been years since I've done high level mathematics (I'm CS now) and the correct jargon escapes me.

Comment: i think you mean $\mathbb{N}^2$ is discrete, while a Hilbert space-filling curve in on a continuous space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cantor's paring function would probably do the job: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function

Comment: If I had the reputation to upvote you, I would. Thank you, this is the direction I need to head in, and you've saved me several hours.

Comment: @Paul:  The Cantor pairing function works with pairs of naturals, not integers.  One way to patch it up is to multiply the single natural side by four and add $0,1,2,3$ for signs $--,-+,+-,++$

Answer (score 2):

Some possibilities as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel#Infinitely_many_coaches_with_infinitely_many_guests_each):

- Prime method: $(x,y)\mapsto p_x^y$ where $p_x$ is the $x$th prime number
- merge method: consider $(x,y)$.  write both numbers with the same amount of digits by adding leading zero's. Now mix $x$ and $y$ to a new number.  To do this, take the first digit of $x$, followed by the first digit of $y$, and so on...
- triangulation method: $(x,y)\mapsto\frac{(c+n)^2+c-n}{2}$

Comment: I am going to provide some helpful feedback. This would have been better a comment. If you could use that site and provide some more concrete response, it can certainly be improved. We try to be careful when using links (although it is impossible not to, because they can go awol for one reason or another). Providing direct answers helps the OP. Regards

Comment: i tried to improve my answer...  i'll also try to keep your feedback in mind...

Comment: Excellent update! Regards